# How to remove invisible margin created by line break in source code on inline-block <a> element

Tags: html, positioning, css

I have a `<a>` element as inline block with a fixed width. I would like to show the `<a>` boxes next to each other, two boxes per row (exactly like in the [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/7/)). BUT if each  box element is in a new line in the source code ([second example](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/8/)), the boxes gain an invisible margin, which you can see if you have a look at the example with e.g. the Chrome dev tools. The width and padding of the parent wrapper, and the margin of each box is exactly calculated, so that the added invisible margin pushes the second box down into the next row.

I could just use the code of the first example (all the  elements without line breaks directly behind each other), but I would like to know how can I remove this invisible margin so that the two boxes again fit next to each other in the wrapper div (like in the first example), even if each `<a>` element is in a new line in the source code.

Examples:

1.) Without line break in code (the layout I want to have): [http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/7/)

2.) With line break in code (added line breaks after `<a>` element changes layout): [http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/8/)

Comment: i didn't understand properly , do you want to format the html or look. Are you talking about when we do viewsource , it should be well formated

Comment: I thought of that, but if the number of link boxes is uneven (like 3 boxes per row and you have 5 boxes), I would like the last 2 boxes to be centered in the middle instead of being aligned to the right or the left.

Comment: Thats a different issue then. It has nothing to do with the new line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>As fcalderan suggested `white-space:nowrap` on the parent should work. See http://jsfiddle.net/kkpKg/ for an example. If it doesn't, then you must be doing something different or wrong.</s>

Ok, now I get it :-)

The best solution **is** to leave out the line breaks, however if you don't want that, the next best would be to comment them out:

```
  <div id="wrap">
       <a href="#">box 1</a><!--
    --><a href="#">box 2</a><!--
    --><a href="#">box 3</a>
  </div>
```

If that isn't a possibility the only thing that I can think of (and is supported by current browsers) is to set the <s>`line-height`</s> `font-size` in `#wrap` to zero and back to original size in the links:

```
#wrap {
  font-size: 0;
}
#wrap a {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Your third example looks exactly how you want it in Chrome, FF and IE8. Maybe it's a specific browser? Or maybe I'm completely missing what you want. Can you post a drawing of how you expect it to look?

Comment: I checked it with Chrome, Safari and FF on OS X. What I want to have is the boxes ordered like in the first example (all boxes in the wrapper, two in the first row, one on the left side in the second row), but with `white-space:nowrap` as in the third example, the third box is outside the rapper in the same row.

Comment: I rewrote the article again, I hope it is a bit more clear now.

Comment: Just tested it, the [first suggestion](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/11/) works fine, but the [second one](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/12/) not so much ... have I got something wrong?

Comment: I could have sworn it worked yesterday, as I tried it :-) Anyway it does work with `font-size`, that however requires you to set the `font-size` to an absolute size on the links, which may not be a good idea if you want to let the user use his chosen font size.

Answer (score 8):

Chris Coyier posted a good article about this problem:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize this question was from a year ago!

Since you've spent so long trying to figure this out, I did some researching and found a similar question. I've adjusted your code here

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/6/)

and it should work now.I placed 5 blocks because of the float case you mentioned before

EDIT: the problem was your margins. You have a 10px padding and 10px margins. If you had made your div 230px (3x10px + 2x100px) you would have gotten the same effect as the first fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, but that still not quite it. I reformulated the question so I hope that it is more clear what I want ...

Comment: Its because the newline adds space. The easy fix for this would just be to make your div 228px. http://jsfiddle.net/mLa93/10/ I'm sure you can ignore the newline in some complicated way but it wouldn't be worth your time.

Comment: You are right, that's an option. I had a closer look, and with FF 4 RC on Mac the line break in the source code adds an invisible margin of 2px on the left and an invisible margin of 4px on the right side. Your right, it's not worth the time really, as I said one can (and that is also what I do atm) just write the <a> tags in one line. I also find this easier than having to change the margin/paddings if one dose not want to change the box width. But still I would like to know what CSS/HTML layout rule causes this behaviour and how to properly fix it.

Comment: Its because your links are inside a div. Usually in html spacing is recognized when it is put inside tags that are not <head> or <body>.

Comment: Good to know, but still not really an answer to this question. I know I changed it quite a bit, so thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `white-space:nowrap` on parent element (the container of your links) and probably `white-space: normal` on links

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work. I put all link boxes into a separate div container with white-space:nowrap and set all links white-space: normal, but the problem is the links then break out of there container box.